# Using icon marker that will be retrived from "URL" instead of saved icon on Google Maps

Tags: android

I'm trying to display marker on Google map. I can do this using a saved icon, for example:
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);

however, the chanllange is, i need to use icon that will be retrived from URL.
like  "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",

any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the BitmapFactory.decodeStream() ... passing in the URL.getImputStream() for the image you want to use during runtime.

Lots of examples of this on the net.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to download the image from the URL, save it locally and then generate the drawable from that local resource.

Comment: I assume you're saying to do this programmatically, so that any number of icon types or images could be added this way. They would all be stored on the device.

Comment: As lawngnomehitman said, whenever you download the picture, it will be stored locally. Downloading it programmatically will only take you time and consume additional resources. Download it and bind it, dont go the hard way :D:D